# using variables inside the curl command not working in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, curl, variable-substitution

I am trying to write a bash script to update certain nodes in my repository. I wrote below script, but it does not seem to be working when I use variables inside `curl`. Below is the code. I tried all possible combinations using `""` inside `curl` statement to resolve the variable. But it does not seem to update the nodes. (I don't get any error when running the script).

I echo'ed the `curl` line like:

```
echo "curl --user admin:admin "$final_add" http://localhost:4502"$a""
```

and placed its output in the script, then the script runs fine and updated the node.

Can anyone provide me some guidance on why cant i update the nodes using the variables in curl.

**Code Sample Below**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Script to set tags"
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"



if [ true ]
then
    echo "**firing curl command for tags2**"

    a="/content/test/events/whats-on/all-about-women-home/2018/wine-tasting/jcr:content"
    i="[/content/cq:tags/sales-stage/pre-sale,/content/cq:tags/sales-stage/special-offer]"
    str=$i
    IFS=,
    ary=($str)

    for key in "${!ary[@]}"; do tags_paths+="-Ftags2=${ary[$key]} "; done 

    final_paths=$(echo $tags_paths | sed "s|[2],]||g")

    final_add="-Ftags2@TypeHint=\"String[]\" ${final_paths//[[[\[\]]/}"

    #have tried this without quotes too --eg : (curl --user admin:admin  $final_add http://localhost:4502$a) it too didnt work
    curl --user admin:admin  "$final_add" http://localhost:4502"$a"
fi
```

Comment: With the script as written, the content of `"$final_add"` is passed to `curl` as *one* argument, containing `-Ftags2@TypeHint="String[]" -Ftags2=/content/cq:tags/sales-stage/pre-sale -Ftags2=/content/cq:tags/sales-stage/special-offer`. Is this what you want?

Comment: I need a command like this: (curl --user admin:admin -Ftags3@TypeHint="String[]" -Ftags3=/content/cq:tags/sales-stage/pre-sale -Ftags3=/content/cq:tags/sales-stage/special-offer  http://localhost:4502/content/something/events/whats-on/all-about-women-home/2018/wine-tasting/jcr:content)   does my $final_add ned to be changed for this?

Comment: You can use `curl -v` option to know the network request details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is mainly with the `-F` flags in the string `$final_paths`.  It is being passed a a single argument to `curl`.  The solution is *not* to un-quote the variable expansion to rely on the shell splitting the string properly.

When you have a list of things that you need to pass to a program as *separate* items, use an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

url='http://localhost:4502'
url+='/content/test/events/whats-on/all-about-women-home/2018/wine-tasting/jcr:content'

tag_paths=(
    '/content/cq:tags/sales-stage/pre-sale'
    '/content/cq:tags/sales-stage/special-offer'
)

curl_opts=( --user "admin:admin" --form "tags3@TypeHint=String[]" )

for tag_path in "${tag_paths[@]}"; do
    curl_opts+=( --form "tags2=$tag_path" )
done

curl "${curl_opts[@]}" "$url"
```

Here, we put the options to pass to `curl` in the array `curl_opts`.  We initiate this array with the things we know will always be there and then add the tag path options by iterating over the array `tag_paths`. 
The double-quoted expansion `"${curl_opts[@]}"` at the end will expand to all elements of the `curl_opts` array, with each element individually quoted.

I've also chosen to build the complete URL at the start as it is static, and I'm using the long option for `curl` as this is a script and we can afford to be a bit more verbose (for the sake of readability).

Doing it this way, the quoting becomes intuitive and you don't need to bother with parsing comma-separated lists, with escaping special characters, or setting `IFS` to some non-default value.

---

The same script, but for `/bin/sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

url='http://localhost:4502'
url="$url/content/test/events/whats-on/all-about-women-home/2018/wine-tasting/jcr:content"

set -- \
    '/content/cq:tags/sales-stage/pre-sale' \
    '/content/cq:tags/sales-stage/special-offer'

for tag_path do
    set -- "$@" --form "tags2=$tag_path"
    shift
done

set -- --user "admin:admin" --form "tags3@TypeHint=String[]" "$@"

curl "$@" "$url"
```

Here, we are restricted to using only one array, `$@`.  Elements are set in this array with `set`.